# Что означает точка в выражении 1/60.?

Tags: java

Заметил, что значения выражений

```
double x = 1234 + 1/60.
```

и

```
double x = 1234 + 1/60
```

разные.

Почему?

Comment: Стоит заметить, что `1234 + 1./60` и `1234 + (double)1/60` приводят к тому же результату

Comment: Возможно, но для передачи сути хотелось краткости.

Comment: @vp_arth а почему не `1234 + 1/(double)60`? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что без точки идет целочисленное деление и в итоге получится не дробное, а целое число (в данном случае получится ноль, т.к. результат округляется вниз к целому числу).

Точка намекает, что число не целое и результат деления будет типа double (0.016666666666666666).

Для успокоения души можно писать и `1/60.0`, но достаточно и просто точки после числа.